# Using pyOptSparseDriver with OpenMDAO and WISDEM

Tags: openmdao

I am using an older version of pyOptSparse (tied to a license) which worked fine in the past with older versions of OpenMDAO (1.x) and WISDEM, but with my current OpenMDAO 3.1.0, with Anaconda/Windows,

when I issue `prob.driver =om.pyOptSparseDriver()`

I get this error:

> AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGUSR1'

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely a bug. We have now fixed it as of OpenMDAO 3.3.1.

A workaround would require you to edit the `pyoptsparse.py` file and replace the default option `signal.SIGUSR1` with None in the "user_terminate_signal" definition.